# Algorithm: Merging std::unordered_maps

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost

I have the following problem:

I have n hashmaps (Let's call them A.1, A.2, ..., A.n) that maps from std::string to boost::variant and I want to merge them into a single hashmap (Let's call that one B) as follows:

1. If A.1, A.2, ... A.n contains the same value for key K, then B should contain the same value for key K.
2. If there exists some key K which is not present in one of the maps A.1, A.2, ... A.n, then B should contain a mapping from key K to value boost::blank.
3. If there exists some value for key K in A.1, A.2, ... A.n that differs from the other values, then B should contain a mapping from key K to value boost::blank.

I have to do this quite a lot, and I know it will become a bottleneck. What is the most efficient way to achieve this? Any library support for merging hashmaps like this?

Edit: If another datastructure is more appropriate, please let me know. I do, however, require O(1) lookups

Comment: Is it possible to do it on the fly? I.e. maintain some result map upon altering any of source n-maps?

Comment: I guess now you have some O(n*m) algorithm where n is number of maps and m is number of entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading this correctly you are looking for an `O(N log N)` solution.  Without having the C++ experience to write a proper implementation what you want to do is something along these lines:

```
1) Push all of the elements from every map into a `Set`   `O(N) + overhead of checking existence O(1)`  
   A)  define the elements of the set by a hash value generated by `Key + Value`   
      a)  that is `A:hello`  creates a different value than `B:hello`  
2) Perform a merge sort `O(N log N)` based on the values  
3) Start at the beginning of your `sorted set` and iterate over the values.  
   A) If a value is found multiple times this satisfies your `3` step  
   B) Your `2` step can be satisifed in `O(1)` time by looking up the key
```

Comment: I guess (1) should be O(N)*log(N), since you need log(N) to put something into set. Or I miss something?

Comment: @denis-bu a hash lookup is `O(1)` and an insert is `O(1)`

Comment: @Woot4Moo - right, for some reason I thought of set as some binary tree set.

Comment: @denis-bu ah yes I could see how that would be problematic

Comment: @Woot4Moo, am I right that N is equals to all elements in all maps. I.e. if n is number of maps and m is number of elements in each map then N= m*n

Comment: @denis-bu correct the size of the input `N` is the summation of the sizes of each of the maps.  So if you have three maps with sizes: 1,2,3 the sum is 6 and therefore N = 6 (in terms of size). It is not necessarily `m*n` because maps may be of different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my algo(just iteration over all elements):

1. `std::unordered_map<string, variant> result`
2. Pick map with most entries in it O(n).
3. Iterate through each element of biggest map -> O(m)

   1. `result[current_key] = current_value`
   2. For each other map -> O(n-1)

      1. Lookup key -> O(1)
      2. If key absent -> `result[current_key] = blank`. Got to next item in biggest map.
      3. [key present] If `current_value != map[key]` -> `result[current_key] = blank`. Got to next item in biggest map.
      4. [key present] Got to next item in biggest map.

That's all. You got O(n) + O(m*n) which equals to O(m*n). Which seems less that @Woot4Moo's algo, since step (2) of @Woot4Moo's algo require O(m*n)*log(m*n).

I'm not sure it is possible to make it faster than O(m*n) in a straightforward way. I guess you'll need some on the fly processing to do this faster. BUT!!! these kind of caches are not very safe. So, consider simple algo at first. Maybe it won't bottleneck your app.